# Writing multiple lines to a file

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write timestamps to a file when clicking on a JButton. Once `.close()` is invoked the data is written to the file and any other writes throw an error. How can I write the data without have to create a new FileWriter and overwriting the previous line?

Comment: Show us you're code. You're probably closing youre file.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of closing, which does this implictly, you call `flush()` on the `FileWriter` object. That keeps it open, but forces the data which has been buffered to be written to the file.
Don't forget to `close()` when you are done writing though.

Comment: Or open the file in append mode if you don't just want to keep the handle open.

Comment: Good point. I was assuming wites happen somewhat frequently, so closing and reopening the file would produce unnecessary overhead. But if that's not the case, closing and opening to append would be my choice, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep the writer open between clicks and close it at some other time (perhaps on form exit), or you can create a new FileWriter for each click and have it append to contents already in the file.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt", true); //true here indicates append to file contents
```

If you choose to keep the writer open between clicks, then you might want to call .flush() on each button press to make sure the file is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Wr {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("viv.txt");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.write("Helloooooooooo");

    bw.close();

    }
}
```